# Valid assignment operators Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, sh

In my bash script i am trying to using the equals (=) operator as input for an IF statement, can this be done?

```
echo "Plese enter an operator as shown in the brackets (-)subtract, (*)Multiply, (+)Add, (/)divide, quit(=)?"
read operator
..........

if [[ $operator == '=' ]]; then 
'do something'
fi
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you could not be able to do this.

```
> operator==
> echo $operator
=
> if [[ $operator == '=' ]]; then echo 'ok'; fi;
ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `shell.sh` :

```
#!/bin/sh
EQUAL="=" #this is our operator
echo "Please enter operator"
read operator

if [ $operator = $EQUAL ]; then
    echo "Entered = "
else
    echo "Not = entered"
fi
```

Execution:

```
:~$ sh shell.sh
Please enter operator
=
Entered = 
:~$ sh shell.sh
Please enter operator
-
Not = entered
:~$
```

[Reference to learn](http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/unix-shell-scripting/ifelse-tutorial.php)